# SQL: Query with subqueries. How to get maximum date?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query ("Datum" means "date") :

```
    'SELECT MCap.Isin,  MCap.Datum,  MCap.MarketCap 
FROM (SELECT MCap.Isin AS myISIN FROM Constituents 
INNER JOIN MCap ON Constituents.Isin = MCap.Isin 
WHERE ((MCap.Datum=DateAdd("m", -' num2str(WindowSize) ', #' ConstituentDate '#)) AND (Constituents.Datum=#' ConstituentDate '#))) AS AvailableISIN 
INNER JOIN MCap ON AvailableISIN.myISIN = MCap.Isin 
WHERE (MCap.Datum IN 
(SELECT max(MCap.Datum) FROM MCap 
WHERE (MCap.Datum>=DateAdd("m", -' num2str(WindowSize) ', #' ConstituentDate '#) AND (MCap.Datum<#' ConstituentDate '#)) GROUP BY MONTH(MCap.Datum), YEAR(MCap.Datum))) ORDER BY MCap.ISIN, MCap.Datum'];
```

This query gives me the marketcapitalisation of every member ("isin") in MCap when it is also in "Constituents" in a given period.

No I want to have only the last date available within the given period. I thoght of something like `max(MCap.Datum)` but ironicly it just gives me the first date available. Somebody here who has a hint?

Using Matlab and Access.

Comment: Edit your question and just put the query in as text.  No one wants to read the code you are using to construct the query.  It does not help in solving your problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Is the second join to MCap and the sub-query in the WHERE clause your attempt at getting the "last available date"? It finds the last MCap(s) in each month but you could do that without the second INNER JOIN to MCap. However, the date criteria in AvailableISIN is different to the criteria in the WHERE sub-query - one has equality operators and the other has inequality operators. From what it looks like, you're getting MCaps for one specific date which correspond to Consituents for another single specific date but only if that date has the last MCap in its month.

Comment: This depends on how your dates are stored, actually. We cannot magically guess that. You will need to add some sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0):

add 'ORDER BY MCap.Datum DESC' to the end of your statement.

In this way, as you iterate over the results, as soon as the MCap.Datum value changes, you know that you have processed all the matching rows with the highest date.

If, according to your data model, only one such row may exist, then you can additionally add 'LIMIT 1' to your statement, and only that row will be returned.